# What's Laravel best way to build an external URL with query string?

Tags: php, url, laravel

I'm currently building a project with Laravel and I need to build URLs with query strings. URL:: functions and url(), action(), etc. are out of the question since they mainly built for internal use. The urls I need to create are external.

A similar example I could give is an external URL for the static images Google Maps api :

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&key=KEY`

If you have the array :

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
array(
    'center'=>'New York, NY',
    'zoom'=>13,
    'size'=>'600x300'
)
```

I'm mainly asking that because it's currently impossible for me to install http_build_url / query extension and because there are many functions that do this internally. I just can't find the best place to "plug" myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to reinvent the wheel (which sucks, sorry to hear), you could do something like this.

```
$queryString = '';
$arrayLength = count($myArray);
foreach ($myArray as $key => $val) {
    $queryString .= urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($val);
    $arrayLength--;
    if ($arrayLength) {
        $queryString .= '&';
    }
}
```

I'd save it as a function, and have a separate function for constructing the url, e.g.

```
function buildUrl($baseUri, $params) {
    return sprintf("%s?%s", $baseUri, buildQueryString($params));
}
```

But I'm not 100 % that this is what you really want, so apologies if I'm wrong.

Edit: Four years later, given that they asked for Laravel methods, I would do something like this:

```
collect($array)->map(function ($value, $key) {
    return urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value);
})->join('&');
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I really wanted to be as optimal as possible by using Laravel native functions, but that will do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: You're not wrong, but the question clearly states that he can't use that function.

Answer (score 0):

Simple string concatenating:

```
$myStr = 'puppies.';
echo 'Dogs have '.$myStr;
```

Output:

> Dogs have puppies.

You can just concatenate the elements of the array with the url string in the same manner:

```
$values = Array(
                'center'=>'New York, NY',
                'zoom'=>13,
                'size'=>'600x300'
                 )

$urlTemp = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmapcenter=';

$url     =  $urlTemp.$values['center']
           .'&zoom='.$values['zoom']
           .'&size='.$values['size']
           .'&key=KEY';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to avoid this to use Laravel native functions as much as possible, but that might be one of the better solutions for now.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you mean by those other functions being "out of the question". Ok, sorry I couldn't be more help.